# ¿Cómo filtrar por caracteres en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datos

Me explico, tengo que trabajar con el número de cédula de clientes, en algunas tablas la información se almacena completa y en otras se separa el número de serio con el digito, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE UNA TABLA(RUT VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY, DV CHAR)
CREATE TABLE SEGUNDA TABLA(RUT VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY)
```

Si yo hiciera un select a ambas tablas los datos los recibo así

```
SELECT * FROM UNA_TABLA
--RESULTADO
RUT      | DV
18XXXXXX   X

SELECT * FROM SEGUNDA_TABLA
--RESULTADO
RUT      
18XXXXXX-X
```

La empresa utiliza un servicio que le administra la base de datos por lo que es imposible cambiar estos datos, pero por medio de programación SQL hay que hacer los respectivos ajustes para comparar. Por ejemplo, si quisiera comparar o traer data donde el rut tiene que ser igual entre ambas tablas podría hacer la siguiente instrucción:

```
CAST(a.RUT+'-'+a.DV AS VARCHAR)=b.Rut
```

Aquí no tengo problema, pero ahora el problema que surge es que quiero utilizar SUBSTRING ya que en una tabla solo tengo el RUT sin el digito verificador y en la otra tabla tengo todo el rut completo con guión.

Por ejemplo: 18XXXXXX | 18XXXXXX-2

Necesito obtener los datos del segundo con un substring antes del guión, esto lo hice así.

```
SUBSTRING(RUT, 1,8)

--RESULTADO=
18XXXXXX
```

Todo bien, pero surgió un problema y es que hay RUT que tienen menos caracteres, es decir no tiene 2 unidades sino que una por ejemplo, 7 millones= 7xxxxxx. Al hacer substring a este Rut, como tiene menos caracteres queda el resultado así:

```
7XXXXXX-
```

Me toma el guion. Y aquí la comparación tiene errores al tener este resultado. Quiero saber si existe la posiblidad de extraer todos los digitos antes del guión. No conozco ningún método, por lo tanto, desconozco si existe esa forma de obtener todos los digitos antes del guión para comprar solo el numero del rut sin guión ni digitos.

El motor de base de datos es SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es relativamente simple, puedes usar `LEFT` y `CHARINDEX`:

```
DECLARE @Rut varchar(11) = '12345678-9';

SELECT LEFT(@Rut,CHARINDEX('-',@Rut)-1) RutSinDV;
```

Comment: Esto era lo que necesitaba saber. Muchas Gracias! Me has ayudado enormemente!

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado al usar esta opción si existe la posibilidad de que no haya un guion en la cadena. Personalmente, prefiero usar `SUBSTRING( @Rut, 0, CHARINDEX('-',@Rut))`